# mysqldump of all databases on Windows 7 with PHP

Tags: php, windows-7, mysql

I am trying to execute mysqldump to export all databases with a small PHP script, but i am stuck with a empty file being created every time the code is executed.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$filename='database_backup_'.date('G_a_m_d_y').'.sql';

$result=exec('mysqldump -p123456 -uroot --all-databases --single-transaction > C:\\tmp' . $filename,$output);

if($output==''){
    echo("Success");
}
else {
    var_dump($output);
} 

?>
```

I have tried to `print_r` the `$output` but obviously this is empty even when my dump fails. I have executed the identical mysqldump manually with mysqldump.exe which works out fine.

Suggestion with passthru did the trick:

```
passthru('C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\mysqldump.exe -uroot -p123456 --all-databases --single-transaction > C:\\tmp' . $filename);
```

Comment: Can you temporarily try `passthru` instead of `exec` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Comment: @karancan, that did the trick, but i would still like to know why exec is failing.

Answer (score 1):

To see what the problem is, change your original statement to the following:

`$result=exec('mysqldump -p123456 -uroot --all-databases --single-transaction > C:\\tmp' . $filename,$output, $returnVar);`

The difference here is I added `$returnVar` as the third parameter to the `exec()` function. This parameter will return the status of the executed command.

Now try `print_r($returnVar)` and see what it says.